# append lines with "\LF" into one line, until finds "\CR\LF"?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a solution to this case, it's a file cleanup.
I have a file "*.csv" that contains several lines, all lines have at the end "\CR\LF", sometimes the file comes with broken lines, so at the end only comes "\LF", missing the "\CR". I need to put all those lines with only "\LF" together in one single line, without any empty spaces, that also have "\CR\LF" at the end.

For example,

[image]

Here's a Python representation of the file's content:

```
file_content = '''\
"A",B,"C","D"\r\n\
"E",F,"G","H"\r\n\
"I",J\n\
       \n\
             ,"K",    \n\
\n\
"L"\r\n\
"O",P,"Q","R"\r\n\
"S",T,"U","V"\r\n\
'''
```

Comment: Are you referring to `'\r'` and `'\n'`?  CR is `'\r'` and LF (aka NL) is `'\n'`.  The `'\L'` and `'\C'` is not a standard notation, AFAIK.

Comment: Please incorporate the text in the image into the question.  Copy'n'paste the material into the edit box, ignoring the preview.  Make sure it looks correct and there are no tabs in the data.  Then select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it as code.  For the icing on the cake, add an unindented line all on its own saying `<!-- language: lang-none -->` above the example.

Comment: this will do ? `re.sub('\s*\n*', '', open('file.csv').read(), re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: @Skycc: does `\s` include carriage return?

Comment: @Jonathan: It may be difficult/impossible for the OP to embed a file into their question that contains a mixture of both `"\n"` and `"\r\n"` characters and have it display in a meaningful way. Perhaps adding a link to a copy of it for downloading would be more appropriate ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) might work).

Comment: Does your file literally have backslash, capital c, capital r in it?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler , good point, maybe `re.sub(r'\s*(?<!\r)\n+', '', open('file.csv').read(), re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions are:

```
import re

file_content = '''\
"A",B,"C","D"\r\n\
"E",F,"G","H"\r\n\
"I",J\n\
       \n\
             ,"K",    \n\
\n\
"L"\r\n\
"O",P,"Q","R"\r\n\
"S",T,"U","V"\r\n\
'''

print "Original:\n", file_content

replace1 = re.sub("(?<!\r) *\n *", '', file_content)
print "Replace1:\n", replace1

replace2 = re.sub("([^\r])( *\n *)+", '\\1', file_content)
print "Replace2:\n", replace2
```

The output from that Python 2 script is:

```
Original:
"A",B,"C","D"
"E",F,"G","H"
"I",J

             ,"K",    

"L"
"O",P,"Q","R"
"S",T,"U","V"

Replace1:
"A",B,"C","D"
"E",F,"G","H"
"I",J,"K","L"
"O",P,"Q","R"
"S",T,"U","V"

Replace2:
"A",B,"C","D"
"E",F,"G","H"
"I",J,"K","L"
"O",P,"Q","R"
"S",T,"U","V"
```